# Convert the directoryinfo into string

Tags: vb.net, directoryinfo

I'm developing a code that extracts the directories names.
The objective is to save the last 2 digits of each folder into a array.
The problem is that it's not possible to convert (directly) to a string array

How do i solve this?

Below is what i got so far

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
Dim a As Integer = Drs.Length
Dim Drs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
Dim Run As String()

                For n = 1 To a
                    Run = Mid(Drs(n), Len(Drs(n)) - 2, 2)
                Next
```

Best Regards

A

Comment: If what you want is the paths then why use `DirectoryInfo` in the first place?  If you just call `Directory.GetDirectories` then you will get back a `String` array.

Comment: You need to resize the array first with Array.Resize(run, run.length) and then set the last element of run to run(run.count-1) = Strings.right(Drs(n),2). In your declaration section, you shall Dim a after Dim Drs . Schmelter solution is obviously much cleaner and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two digits or characters of each folder-name? If the latter ...

```
Dim Run As String() = Drs.Select(Function(d) d.Name.Substring(d.Name.Length - 2)).ToArray()
```

This obviously fails with a directory which name is shorter than 2 characters.